# How to save plots in ngspice

Tags: ngspice, plot

Is there a command or an option in the "plot" command that can generate png/jpg images of the plots?

Answer (score 5):

hardcopy [file name] [plot arguments]

i.e.

```
hardcopy xyPlot.ps v(1) v(2)
```

Then you can convert postscript files to jpg or png using gimp or many other tools.

Comment: Is it a way to make this in a single step?

Comment: Is it possible to get outputs for multiple variables?